# Testing login session with Behat

Tags: php, bdd, behat, cartalyst-sentinel

I am testing an XML and JSON REST API with [Behat](http://behat.org/en/latest/). For authentication, I use [Sentinel](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel). Now, if I log in a user through Behat, and I test the status of the login session, the API returns a negative response (e.g. user not logged in). When I do the exact same thing manually in a browser using AJAX requests, everything works fine. So the end result is fine but the scenario fails. Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I'll elaborate a bit more on the setup of the app, which is based on [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/), [Twig](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/), [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) and [Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0).

The API has some routes to create, show (yes or no) and delete user session. So logging in a user is done by POSTing an email address and password to `/session.json` or `/session.xml`. Behind the scenes, the controller will basically call `Sentinel::authenticate(...)`.

This all works fine in the browser. If I perform a GET request to `/session.json`, I will see the user is logged in correctly. If I follow the same steps with Behat, I will get the right return value on the POST request, so Sentinel says the user is logged in. But the GET request will tell me the user is not logged in.

To give you an idea, the Behat scenario looks something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Logging in a user
  Given I have a user with "<email>" and "<password>"
  And I use the "<format>" format
  When I log in the user with "<email>" and "<password>"
  Then the "success" message should be "session.active"

  Examples:
    | email | password | format |
    | a@b.c | 32165487 | xml    |
    | c@b.a | 89056734 | json   |
```

In the context I use the [Requests](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/) library to actually perform the requests. So Behat acts as a regular client.

Comment: If possible add some code on how you did the authentication and what error you have and what validation you are using. Possible that may help others to give you a specific answer, the actual format of the question is not very specific.

Comment: I added a bit more info on the setup. It's a stripped down version but that's basically that what it does.